# select only date from datetime in oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to select only date from a datetime column in oracle, but unable to do it. Can anybody give me quick solution please?

So, my column results like below:

02/14/2014 12:00:00.000 AM

but I wanted in below format:

02/14/2014

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
select to_char(column,'dd/mm/yyyy') dual;
```

Comment: thank you for the super fast reply. It works.

Comment: You should note that this is only desirable if your client is somthing like SQL Plus or toad. If the client is a java or C# application or a reporting tool it's better to do the formatting there so you preserve the type.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I wanted for Toad only